# python netifaces - How to get currently used network interface

Tags: python, linux, ip-address

i using netifaces in python to get local ip address, but how to pick currently used (by system) network interface? Help me please. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "currently used"? A system may have multiple active network interface (and each interfaces may have multiple ip addresses).

Comment: I mean preferred network interfaces.  For example, i have eth0 and wlan0. eth0 is preferred interface and this is what i want to get.

Comment: How is it "preferred"?  Do you mean, "how do I figure out which interface is being used as the default route?"

Comment: Yes, somethink like that. Simply determine the current used interface in python

Comment: Example: mymac = "getHwAddr('determinate current used interface')"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear what you're asking, because a system does not necessarily have a singled "used" interface.  A system may have multiple interfaces with addresses, and may be using all of them to contact different systems.

A system will usually (but not always!) have a "default route" out one interface, which is typically used to contact hosts to which the system is not directly connected.  If this is what you want, you can use the Python [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) module, like this:

```
>>> import netifaces
>>> def_gw_device = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]
```

This will get you the name of the device used by the default IPv4 route.  You can get the MAC address of that interface like this:

```
>>> macaddr = netifaces.ifaddresses('enp0s25')[netifaces.AF_LINK][0]['addr']
```

You can of course get the same information by parsing the output of the `ip` command, but using the `netifaces` module is much cleaner.

Comment: To be sure, the `netifaces` documentation spells out these complications and common false assumptions in a fair amount of detail.